# Reference to C# Assembly in different path from C++/CLI DLL

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli

I want to write a plugin for a software, which loads normal 32Bit DLL's as plugins.

Because my experience in C# is much better, i planned to use a C++/CLI Assembly as
wrapper which then delegates the function calls to the 'real' C# plugin.

But i have a problem with this. I tested that the C++/CLI DLL gets loaded correctly.
Now i added the C# assembly as reference to the C++/CLI DLL. The problem is, that when I have the C# DLL in the same directory, the Software wants to load it as a plugin directly and the Software crashes. If i place the C# DLL in a subdirectory it can't be found by C++/CLI DLL.

I tried different solutions i found on the web to let the C++/CLI Assembly find the C# Assembly in a subdirectory, but they all didn't work:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="DLL" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Did not work. It seems like the app.config is ignored when creating a C++/CLI DLL.

Adding `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath("DLL");` as first command in the assembly does not work as the DLL only has direct function calls and there is nothing like a real 'entry point'.

Another thing i found was placing the method `Assembly currentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)` in the DLL. But i couldn't get the compiler to recognize the Assembly keyword, although i used `using namespace System::Reflection;`.

So i would be thankful if someone has any idea how to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have to use 2 assemblies (C++ and C#) if you use my [Project Template for Unmanaged Exports](http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/csharpprojecttemplateforunmanagedexports).

I've heard of some people who wrote templates based on mine to create 3rd party plugins.
The newest one I've seen was [one for Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/482781/topic/4404278)

**Edit:**
Even if you create plain DLL with C#, you might still need to reference other assemblies.
However, it seems that you can get around using C# pretty okay, so you can use AssemblyResolve from there, too.

Comment: I think this would be create if it works. But your link to the Template does not work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? It should point to http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/csharpprojecttemplateforunmanagedexports  at the bottom, you can find the template.

Comment: Was getting just an empty page with also no sourcecode. Link works on IE but not on my Firefox 4.

Comment: Your template works. Thanks. Although it might be a bit offtopic: As the software uses char* for text i must return them with 'return (char*)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("Text")'. But how do I assure they get freed after use. I can not make this is the current funtion call since it is the return value.

Comment: You should be able to return just a String. The default marshalling for String is a pointer to an Ansi Char. By convention, a returned String should be freed by the caller. Otherwise it would be just weird.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Assembly::Load(path_to_managed_dll)` before calling any functions that use the managed DLL.